# What does ND abbreviation stand for in athletics results

Tags: terminology, track-and-field

I saw this abbreviation (ND) in jumps result at a local championship.
What does this stand for?

I am guessing something like did not meet the minimum length but would like to be sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No Distance - e.g. if a long jumper fails to perform a legal jump.

Comment: What makes an jump ilegal: touching the line?